# Is it appropriate to plug drupal.stackexchange.com on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

This question might be irrelevant while drupal.stackexchange.com is still in beta, but, given that 75% of my website work is in Drupal, I'm especially excited to see this site in beta and really want it to be a success.

Once it becomes public, is it appropriate to mention drupal.stackexchange.com in my Drupal-related answers on www.stackoverflow.com? I'm thinking of a parenthetical mention at the end of my responses, pointing out that the site is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's appropriate as I [suggested the same thing](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-promote-drupal-answers/18#18) (and even [started doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195871/drupal-7-calling-custom-content-type-field-into-page-tpl/5196686#5196686) on SO). :-)

However I prefer mentionning Drupal Answers in a *comment instead of the answer itself* because it feels less intrusive / spam-like that way.

Comment: Jeff [agrees about using comments](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114/is-there-a-way-to-promote-drupal-se-on-questions-about-drupal-on-so/117#117), but *"only do this for users who have a number of Drupal questions in their history, please!"*

Answer (score 3):

A post should be about providing the best possible answer to the question being asked. Period. Sure, if a reference to this site somehow makes your answer more relevant *to the question*, go for it. But anything beyond that should be avoided.

I can appreciate your desire to promote this site, but adding signatures or standard sign-offs or parenthetical asides go against the nature of Stack Exchange.

Don't worry, once the site gets rolling, there will be plenty of opportunities to cross-promote your mutual interests between sites. But we'll do it within the bounds of good Q&A.

Comment: One point missed here is that a lot of Drupal questions on SO are not programming questions, this is probably a better place for those.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Stack Overflow has always accepted Drupal questions, even if the questions were not about programming. I guess they have been accepted as questions about a developer tool, and it is now difficult to say "you need to ask questions about which Drupal module to use on Drupal Answers." Ask Different is in the same situation, as part of the questions asked there are still on-topic for Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to ask questions on *Drupal Answers* should be limited, and it should not be done in a comment for a question about Drupal asked on *Stack Overflow*. For what I can see, most of the users (who don't have a high reputation on Stack Overflow) would just ask the same exact question on *Drupal Answers*, with the effect of having the same question in two sites. This should not happen, and the OP should be informed that he can ask to migrate the question to the moderators of Stack Overflow.

I understand the need to promote *Drupal Answers*, but at the same time I think users are free to ask the questions where they prefer. I think that questions that are related to Drupal, but which are not about programming, should preferably asked on *DA*, rather than *SO*. At the same time, I think that users that ask most of their questions on *SO* because most of the questions are about PHP, and not Drupal, should not be forced to ask their few questions about Drupal on *DA*.

To notice that the "drupal" tags on Stack Overflow has a reference to *DA*. It is not enough for redirecting users to *DA*, but at least there is a reference to *DA* that can be read from *Stack Overflow* users.
Most of the promotion should be done outside the Stack Exchange network, which anyway promotes *DA* showing in a block questions asked on *DA*. If you want *DA* promoted on *SO*, ask more questions on *Drupal Answer*; the more questions are asked, the more probable is that a question on *DA* is shown in another SE site, and that a new user registers an account on *DA*.